# How to validate an xml file using a schema file in C programming language using libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

I have been trying to validate XML file using schema file in my C Code. The validation happens successfully stating whether the file is valid or invalid.

But my issue is it prints valid/invalid only. There should be a report/output as to what was missing in the xml file in case it was invalid. May be something like the line number in XML file.

Hope, i have made my self clear.

Here's my C code:-

```
 int validateXmlFile()
{
    int iError = 0;
    xmlDocPtr pDoc;
    xmlDocPtr pSchemaDoc;
    xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr pSchemaCtxt;
    xmlSchemaPtr pSchema;
    xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr pValidCtxt;
    char * xmlFilename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\pbhatia\\Desktop\\Schema\\ipt_config.xml";
    char * schemaFilename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\pbhatia\\Desktop\\Schema\\ipt_config.xsd";

    PRNT(printf("Schema file : %s \n", schemaFilename));
    PRNT(printf("XML file : %s \n", xmlFilename));

    pDoc = xmlReadFile(xmlFilename, NULL, XML_PARSE_NONET);
    if (!pDoc)
        return -1;

    pSchemaDoc = xmlReadFile(schemaFilename, NULL, XML_PARSE_NONET);
    if (!pSchemaDoc)
        return -2;

    pSchemaCtxt = xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt(pSchemaDoc);
    if (!pSchemaCtxt)
        return -3;

    pSchema = xmlSchemaParse(pSchemaCtxt);
    if (!pSchema)
        return -4;

    pValidCtxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(pSchema);
    if(!pValidCtxt)
        return -5;

    // Attempting to validate xml with schema
    xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt(pSchemaCtxt);
    xmlFreeDoc(pSchemaDoc);

    iError = xmlSchemaValidateDoc(pValidCtxt, pDoc);
        if (iError == 0)
        PRNT(printf("Document in %s is valid \n", xmlFilename));
    else
        PRNT(printf("Document in %s is NOT valid \n", xmlFilename));

    xmlSchemaFree(pSchema);
    xmlFreeDoc(pDoc);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Priyanka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading [`xmllint.c`](http://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/xmllint.c) source code it turns out that you may setup callbacks for errors and warnings in the context, using [`xmlSchemaSetValidErrors`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html#xmlSchemaSetValidErrors). In simplest case you forward `fprintf` and it would simply print errors.

```
xmlSchemaSetValidErrors(ctxt,
    (xmlSchemaValidityErrorFunc) fprintf,
    (xmlSchemaValidityWarningFunc) fprintf,
    stderr);
```

UTSL :)

Comment: They are in another SO question: [libxml2 get validation errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107423/libxml2-get-validation-errors)

Comment: After implementing the required functions, I am able to get the error/warnings. But it doesn't show at what line in xml file the error occurred(i.e. validation failed). Can we achieve this some how??

Answer (score 0):

not an answer to your schame part, but an answer to your "where to find" the error:

```
  FILE *f = fopen("/temp/xml_err.log", "a");

  xmlDocPtr doc;
  if (f) {
    xmlSetGenericErrorFunc(f, NULL);
  }
  doc = xmlParseMemory(xmlstr, XMLMAXSTRSIZE);
  if (f) {
    fclose(f);
  }
```