# XML schema validation - pass schema file content as string and not as file

Tags: c, libxml2

I am trying to validate XML file using a schema file using C programming language.
Is there a way to pass/store Schema file content in `char*` variable. Something like below:

```
char *schemaContent = "complete schema file content.....";
```

Is there a way to attain something of this sort?

Answer (score 0):

Use [xmlReadMemory](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadMemory) to obtain the `xmlDoc` from `char *`. In your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453914/how-to-validate-an-xml-file-using-a-schema-file-in-c-programming-language-using) replace `xmlReadFile` with `xmlReadMemory`. The [io1.c](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#InputOutput) example from libxml page uses `xmlReadMemory`.